# UIWebview URL handling

Tags: html, ios, url, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview wherein I feed different kinds of text like links, simple text, emoticons. It is customize that it will chop a long link into several chunks for eg.

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s480x480/525188_10200372945753969_1256081282_n.jpg
```

into

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-</BR>
d-a.akamaihd.net/hphot</BR>
os-ak-ash3/s480x480/52</BR>
5188_10200372945753969</BR>
_1256081282_n.jpg
```

I tried removing the method that chops it into several chunks but this is what I get...

```
https://fbcdn-sphotosd-
a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-
ash3/s480x480/525188_10200372945753969_1256081282_n.jpg
```

The link is full and working, however on the UI it doesn't display correctly, if only it would automatically create a new line without breaking the link...

So the problem is that because there is a trailing html element  the link automatically gets broken my question is...

Is there a way to handle such scenario wherein I can include the HTML element tags into the link yet doesn't break the link or better yet just make the long link display correctly?

Comment: can you please paste your NSString object?

Comment: Here's a sample: https://fbcdn-sphotos-</BR>
d-a.akamaihd.net/hphot</BR>
os-ak-ash3/s480x480/52</BR>
5188_10200372945753969</BR>
_1256081282_n.jpg